# Solve the following PDE with fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the following PDE
$$u_t=u_xx+δ(x)δ(t)$$
BC s:
$$\lim_{|x|\to \infty}u(x,t)=0$$
IC s:
$$u(x,0)= δ(x).$$
 solve pde with fourier tranform

Comment: What is the meaning of $lim┬(|x|→∞)⁡u(x,t)=0$?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution $u\in{\mathscr D}'(\mathbb R^2)$?

Comment: @maha: I can see you have posted different kinds of problems. So, are these problems coming from different courses? By the way, do you consider accepting courses?

Comment: Have you heard of 'method of characteristics'?